# setting user.home in eclipse.init

Tags: java, eclipse

I understand that eclipse considers HOME variable maintained in the environment variable for git configuration file.
But I want to overwrite this by passing it as an argument from eclipse.init file.
I maintained this info as follows,

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2014m
-Duser.home=C:/personal

But somehow this value is not considered for creating .GitConfig file.

Could some one please tell is it right way to overwrite the value?

Thanks,
Kitty

Answer (score 2):

As you stated EGit is checking the environment variable `HOME` (see in the documentation [Setting_up_the_Home_Directory_on_Windows](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Setting_up_the_Home_Directory_on_Windows)).

But the **environment variable** `HOME` is not the same as the **JVM option** `-Duser.home`.

One solution could be to create a start script and define the environment variable before starting Eclipse.

```
set HOME=c:/personal
exclipse.exe
```